# Loading Similar typed values as one value into a table

Tags: mysql, ssis

I have a column in a database that contains Moroccan cities. but each city is typed many time with different ways . please check the list to see what I mean :

```
CASA
```

CASA

CASA
  CASABLANCA
CAS
CASA
CASA (BERNOUSSI
CASA BLANCA
CASA 
CASABALANCA
CASABLABCA
CASABLACA
CASABLANA
CASABLANCA
CASABLANCA.
CASAZBLACA
CASBLANCA

FES
FES TAZA
FES-TAZA
FEZ

INEZEGUANE
INEZGANE
INZEGAN
INZEGANE
INZEGGAN
INZEGGANE
INZGANE

KSAR EL KBIR
KSAR EL KEBIR
KSAR KEBIR
KSAR LAKBIR
KSAR LEKBIR
KSER EL KEBIR

LAAYOUN
LAAYOUNE

I want to get a table that contains all the cities but with one value. So, How can I Transform my table using SSIS to get that distinct values in a new table .

Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way would be to cleanse your data first by updating the columns and then this would be a much simpler job.

However, if you just wanted distinct Moroccan cities then you could just create manually.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_cities_in_Morocco

Grab the city names from there, export to csv etc. and manipulate into a table..